# the current recommended way to Play youtube video in all android device

Tags: android, flash, html, youtube

Hello i have a video application such that all the videos exist on `Youtube` . now `Google` says in their IO that the `Youtube API` for `android` will be available soon . that was 2.5 months ago . any how , i have a `Html5` player using `javascript` plus a flash player for `YouTube` , but `HTML5` does not work on all devices and the `flash` player wont work on `Android` 4.0 and up . is there a way to play the video within the app and support all devices !!

Answer (score 0):

You could launch an Intent to launch the built-in Youtube app:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("vnd.youtube:"+ YOUR_VIDEO_ID));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: okey @Yuval ,you haven't read the question probably but i tried this approach it takes 2 seconds to open the Youtube app .

Comment: Open the YouTube app is not that slow. I think @user4o01 should use the solution above.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following while programming for browsers:
Create a HTML5 video using this example:
[Video For Everybody](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody)

If you look at that, at the end you see when all sources arent supported, it will take a flash file. If that also doesnt work you could try to use a library as a fallback option even after the flash in that example. I am not sure (little experience with programming for android) but if the sources, flash and javascript/other libraries dont work... I dont know. Sorry :)

Possibly you could use a pure javascript solution?

I hope you can get a bit further with my answer, although it could very well be known to you already.

Take care!